# Using helpers from mounted engine in parent Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I mounted engine to the application, and I want to use one of the engine's helper all over the parent application.

In my Dummy app I put this in Dummy's `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Sourcebuster::CookieSettersHelper
  before_filter :set_sourcebuster_data
  helper_method :extract_sourcebuster_data

  private

    def set_sourcebuster_data
      set_sourcebuster_cookies
    end

end
```

And it was ok.

But when I mounted it to the real app, helper from engine just don't work.

How to load it, so it can do the stuff all over the parent app?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I tried to `set_sourcebuster_data` inside namespaced engine (http://lvh.me:3000/sourcebuster).

`before_filter` in **application's** `application_controller.rb` don't work in this case.

Added it to **engine's** `application_controller.rb`, now it's doing the stuff all over the app)